# Bootstrap 4 navbar button not working where is my fault

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I did research on the internet but I couldn't solve my problem because my English is bad. I apologize. I open the subject again. My navbar toogle not working. 
ı didnt understand. where is my problem?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

    <div class="container-fluid mt-3 p-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="navbaritem"><span style="color:skyblue" >FİRMA</span> ADI</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nvbCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bootstrap 4 navbar

**You have not added any menu item. Nor have you given any menu item using the collapse class, what will it do and what it shows.**

> Try this and put your content inside it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="margin:24px 0;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="navbaritem"><span style="color:skyblue" >FİRMA</span> ADI</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Mymenu" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="Mymenu" >
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">menu 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: ı just did ctrl c + ctrl v  but still same :/

Comment: If you are using the same CDN. Then its working.                                                                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: ı understand now. my fault missing cdn ?

Comment: Ok, I also felt CDN is missing. That's why sent CDN to check